# Why is the definition of colors in a pd.DataFrame plot so strange?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to color the lines in a plot from a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm


df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4],[4, 5, 6]])
color=iter(cm.nipy_spectral(np.linspace(0,1,len(df.columns))))
for i in df.columns:
    c=next(color)
    df[i].plot(marker="o", mec = c, color=[c])
```

Why is the color definition not the same? I would have assumed either:

```
df[i].plot(marker="o", mec = c, color=c)
```

or

```
df[i].plot(marker="o", mec = [c], color=[c])
```

but not a mixed version.
Adding brackets to **mec** or leaving them at **color** throws an error
*Invalid RGBA argument: 0.0*
or
*Invalid RGBA argument: [array([0., 0., 0., 1.])]*
respectively.

Comment: This question asks for why `mec = c, color=[c]` works fine, but `color = c` or `mec = [c]` do not work.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Interestingly, `plt.plot(df[i].values, "-o", mec=c, color=c)` works!

Comment: The reason is mainly that the pandas `plot` function is heavily overloaded to perform all kinds of different tasks. Getting a coherent interface in such case is utterly hard and frequently results in bugs. E.g. you want to supposrt different colors for bar bar or scatter plots, so you need to support `color` taking a list. But then how do you distingish a list of colors from a list of RGB values? This requires a lot of if/else stuff and often enough one fails to get these correct.

Comment: ok, so than this is a kind of expected behavior and not an error of using i.e. iter on my side.

Comment: Well, it's not really expected, more like an unfortunate oversight from pandas at that point. But yes, you're not doing anything wrong here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Worth raising an issue?

Comment: @Sheldore You can sure do that. From my experience though, it would help more to actually find the problem in the code and directly fix it.